# Python 3.6 ошибка в коде, при выводе и сравнении min and max значений в массиве

Tags: python-3.x

#привет, уважаемое сообщество. Прошу подсказать, в чем ошибка при сравнении чисел в массиве. Макс значение выдает правильно, а мин всегда одно  и тоже. Хотя значения в цикле перебираются, но не всегда устанавливается минимальное верно.

```
import random

x=[]

for i in range(100):
    x.append(random.randint(0,50))

min=max=x[0]

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]>=max:
        max=x[i]
    if x[i]<=min:
        mim=x[i]
    if i==99:    
        print(x)
        print("max is: "+str(max)+" min is: "+str(min))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут ошибочка вкралась:   mi**m**=x[i]

И вы же знаете, что можно использовать встроенные функции?

```
  mn = min(x)
  mx = max(x)
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ!. Странно, что мой интерпретатор даже не ругался на эту переменную. Теперь буду сбрасывать ядро jupiter notebook. Что бы он не брал значения из памяти и показывл не определенные переменные. Спасибо еще раз!
Встроенные функции можно применить. Но сейчас цель- решить без них.

Comment: А почему он должен ругаться? С его точки зрения все более-менее нормально - при неком условии для min установить mim

Comment: И то верно говорите. Получается mim новая переменная, которую сразу и определил, но нигде не вызвал. Это C++ бы выдал ошибку или предупреждение, но Python- этим не заморачивается.